# www directory in WAMP menu

Tags: user-interface, menu, wamp

The latest WAMP server version installation does not display www directory in the main menu, which in the previous versions was always an item below localhost, phpMyAdmin etc.
Is there any way to bring this back to the menu? Is there any file that serves what is displayed in the menu that can be edited?